# Python does not recognise text files in a directory

Tags: python, directory, filepath, glob

The following piece of code works fine, reads all the text files in the specified directory:

```
files_ = glob.glob('D:\Test files\Case 1\*.txt')
```

But when I change the path to another directory, it gives me an empty list of files:

```
files_ = glob.glob('D:\Test files\Case 2\*.txt')
print files_ >> []
```

Both directories contain a couple of text files. Text file names and sizes are different though. 
It's really wired and I couldn't think of any thing to solve the problem. Has anyone faced such a problem?

Comment: what is the output from `os.listdir` on that directory?

Comment: The actual path is `D:\Test files\B1\1rgb` and `os.listdir` gives the error: `WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\Test files\\B1\x01rgb/*.*'`

Comment: You need to either use forward slashes, like `'D:/Test files/Case 2/*.txt'`, a raw string prefix, like `r'D:\Test files\Case 2\*.txt'`, or escape the backslash characters in the string, like `'D:\\Test files\\Case 2\\*.txt'` for Windows paths. In addition you may also need to enclose them in double quote `"` characters if they contain space character(s), such as `r'"D:\Test files\Case 2\*.txt"'`.

Comment: Thanks @martineau, the double backslash did the job. But why single backslash works for the first directory, but not for the other one? Does directory name matter?

Comment: @PyLearner: Not sure what you mean -- ALL backslashes in the string need to be doubled in order to represent a single literal \ character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either *escape* your backslashes:

```
files_ = glob.glob('D:\\Test files\\Case 2\\*.txt')
```

Or specify that your string is a *raw* string (meaning backslashes should not be specially interpreted):

```
files_ = glob.glob(r'D:\Test files\Case 2\*.txt')
```

What happened to break your second `glob` is that `\1` turned into the ASCII control character `\x01`.  The error message contains a clue to that:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\Test files\\B1\x01rgb/*.*'
```

Notice how a `\1` turned into the literal `\x01`.  The reason your first directory worked is that you basically got lucky and didn't accidentally specify any special characters:

```
'\T'
Out[27]: '\\T'

'\B'
Out[28]: '\\B'

'\1'
Out[29]: '\x01'
```